# What is wrong with my JavaScript Code using the innerHTML method?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I'm trying to change the text in an h2 element with the simplest code but don't get what I'm doing wrong :

html

```
<h2 id="tries">Number of tries : 0</h2>
```

javascript

```
document.getElementById("tries").innerHTML = 'new text';
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong wiht that. You asked JS to replace the innerHTML, and JS done that.

If you want to change only the value after the `":"` then here is an example where I placed a `span` into the the `p` and I change the innerHTML of this `span`.

```js
function changeText(value) {
  //this is the point
  document.getElementById("tries-value").innerHTML = value;
}

const input = document.querySelector("input");
input.addEventListener("change", (e) => changeText(e.target.value));

changeText(input.value)
```

```html
<h2 id="tries">Number of tries : <span id="tries-value">0</span></h2>
<label for="input-number">Change the input:</label>
<input id="input-number" value="10" type="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just guess you did that and as you can see, it will fail

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
document.getElementById("tries").innerHTML = 'new text';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="tries">Number of tries : 0</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

You can first do DOM Operations if the DOM is actually loaded, so you just listen to the [window.load](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event and it will work

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.getElementById("tries").innerHTML = 'new text';
});
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="tries">Number of tries : 0</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry but it does'nt helps, because the original issue is not solved.